# AND operator doesn't work in 3 conditions

Tags: javascript, operators

The `&&` operator doesn't work with 3 conditions in my `if` statement. It is working in 2 conditions.

**This is working (In two conditions)**

```
if($("[name='menu[]']:checked").val() == 1 && $("[name='menu[]']:checked").length < 2) {        
    alert('if first menu is checked, you have to check at least one other menu also');    
    return false;
}
```

**This is also working ( In two conditions)**

```
if ($("[name='menu[]']:checked").val() == 2 && $("[name^='submenu']:checked").length == 0) {
    alert('You have to select submenu with second menu');        
    return false;
}
```

**But what is wrong here in three conditions**

```
if($("[name='menu[]']:checked").val() == 1&2 && $("[name='menu[]']:checked").length < 2 && $("[name^='submenu']:checked").length == 0) {        
    alert('You are selecting first and second menu, but missed submenu of second menu');        
    return false;
}
```

If I add `||` instead of `&&` operator before last condition, it works. But `OR` operator doesn't fulfill project requirement, `AND` is compulsory.

Comment: `== 1&2` is invalid syntax. You need to separate those checks. However it appears that you're checking if the element's value is both `1` and `2` at the same time, which is clearly not possible. I think you may need an OR condition instead. Also note that `val()` returns a string, yet you're comparing this to an integer. It will work through type coercion, but isn't best practice.

Comment: `&&` isn't a jQuery operator. And as Rory highlighted in the comment, you've incorrect syntax in your code. But even if you correct it by using two checks having `&&` in between, your code will still not work as the value can't be 1 and 2 at the same time.

Comment: `== 1&2` doesn't even make sense.  A value cannot equal two different values.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, but why it is working in with two condition. If I removed last condition, '== 1&2' works

Comment: Because, as I mentioned above, `== 1&2` isn't valid syntax for comparing multiple values. The `&` operator is a bitwise AND. In this case it outputs `0`, so that may be the reason the condition worked; it's equivalent to `el.val() == 0`

Comment: well, it's not invalid syntax strictly speaking, it's just doing a bitwise operation which is definitely not the intent.

Comment: @dgeare yep, just edited the comment to explain that. Thanks. My first comment should be 'not valid syntax when attempting to check multiple values'

Answer (score 0):

Here I've broken it out, to better illustrate the comments being made on the original question. (Note, the first statement was changed to a nested OR statement, as a variable will never be both 1 and 2 at the same time).

```js
if(
 (
  $("[name='menu[]']:checked").val() == 1 || 
  $("[name='menu[]']:checked").val() == 2
 ) && 
 $("[name='menu[]']:checked").length < 2 && 
 $("[name^='submenu']:checked").length == 0
) {        
 alert('You are selecting first and second menu, but missed submenu of second menu');        
 return false;
}
```